# Melhor FrameWork para JSON

Tags: json, framework

Estou com um projeto para android e preciso de uma framework para fazer troca de informações via webservice.

Answer (score 2):

Existe a biblioteca Volley mantida pelo Google que tem como finalidade ajudar as implementações de comunicacão HTTP.

O Google fornece uma pagina de documentação: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Exemplo de uso:

```
public void initVolley(Context applicationContext) {
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext);
}

public void doPost(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.POST,
    URL,
    jsonObject,
    new Response.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // Do something...
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // Do something...
        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
```